# using regex - or any other solution - to change number (1-)(2-) to <ul><li> tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem using regex in C#, or at least what I think it will be the solution of my problem, I have this string for example:

> "Go to Original Budget screen, \n1- Check if Original Budget is Original Budget CV\n- Check if Remaining Budget is Remaining Budget CV\n- Check new field Exchange rate \n- Check new field Original Budget FC \n- Check new field Remaining Budget FC \n2- Check renamed  field under Weekly Details:\n- Check if In Flow is In Flow CV \n- Check if Out Flow is Out Flow CV \n- Check new field In Flow FC\n- Check new field Out Flow FC"

I need it to be :

> Go to Original Budget screen
>
> - Check if Original Budget is
>     Original Budget CV
>   - Check if Remaining Budget is Remaining
>       Budget CV
>   - Check new field Exchange rate
>   - Check new
>       field Original Budget FC
>   - Check new field Remaining Budget
>       FC
> - Check renamed field under Weekly Details:
>   - Check if In Flow is In Flow CV
>   - Check if Out Flow is
>       Out Flow CV
>   - Check new field In Flow FC
>   - Check new
>       field Out Flow FC

so if the simple example didn't get the message, I want to put `<li>` and `<ul>` tag in that string so I can use it on a web application

this is a simple of my code:

```
  private string regexmethod(string field)
    {
        string strRegex = @"^(.+?)\\n[\d|\w]-\W+";
        Regex CatchBetweenTheFirstDot = new Regex(@"\\n[\d|\w]-\W+(.+?)\\n[\d|\w]-\W+");
        Regex CatchTheNumbers = new Regex(@"\\n[\d|\w]-\W+");
        Regex CatchFirstLineBeforDot = new Regex(strRegex);
        Regex CatchInsideFirstRegex = new Regex(@"\\n-\W+");
        var matchFirst = CatchFirstLineBeforDot.Matches(field);
        var matchBetween = CatchBetweenTheFirstDot.Matches(field);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        if (matchFirst.Count > 0)
            str.Append(matchFirst[0].Value);
        foreach (Match matchItem in matchBetween)
        {
            str.Append("<ul><li>");
            string newvalue = matchItem.Value;
            var matchTheInside = CatchInsideFirstRegex.Matches(newvalue);
            for (int i = 0; i < matchTheInside.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    newvalue.Replace(matchTheInside[i].Value, @"<ul><li>");
                }
                else
                {
                    newvalue.Replace(matchTheInside[i].Value, @"<\li><li>");
                }
            }
            if (newvalue.Length > 0)
            {
                newvalue += "</li></ul>";
                str.Append(newvalue);
            }

        }
```

this is what i got so far, but it didn't work with me.

any help will be thankful.

Comment: What is the expected output given your input? those `Lorem Ipsum`s don't make any sense.

Comment: list and sub list like the following:
Go to Original Budget screen
<ul><li>Check if Original Budget is Original Budget CV</li>
<ul><li>Check if Remaining Budget is Remaining Budget CV</li>
<li>Check new field Exchange rate</li>
<li>Check new field Original Budget FC</li>
<li>Check new field Remaining Budget FC</li>
</ul><li>2- Check renamed field under Weekly Details:</li>
<ul><li>Check if In Flow is In Flow CV</li>
<li>Check if Out Flow is Out Flow CV</li>
<li>Check new field In Flow FC</li>
<li>Check new field Out Flow FC</li></ul>
</ul>

Comment: What is the datasource of this list? There has to be an easier way of going about this.

Comment: the source of the text is from a excel data sheet. I used "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel", I extract the text from the cells, but it didn't extract it as html style. so I need to change it so it can be uploaded to a website

Comment: And where does the excel spreadsheet get the data from? Perhaps you need to parse the HTML too.

Comment: some data entry guy used to insert this data manually

Comment: I don't see how your input text correlates to desired output html. First html sample have incorrect items count. Second html sample have incorrect structure.

Comment: why it is so hard to understand? I just wanna add <li> and <ul> tags in that string, who cares where the data comes!

Comment: @JohnSmith why is it so hard to provide correct sample?

Comment: when I put the html tags in the question, it automatically change it to dots

Answer (score 1):

Here is class for parsing lines from your text:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public static bool TryParse(string s, out ListItem item)
    {
        item = null;
        if (!IsListItem(s) && !IsOrderedListItem(s))
            return false;

        item = new ListItem { IsOrdered = IsOrderedListItem(s),
                              Text = GetItemText(s) };
        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsListItem(string s) {
        return Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^- .*");
    }

    private static bool IsOrderedListItem(string s) {                
        return Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d+- .*");
    }

    private static string GetItemText(string s) {
        return s.Substring(s.IndexOf('-') + 1).Trim();
    }

    public bool IsOrdered { get; private set; }
    public int Index { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public string Html {
        get { return String.Format("<li>{0}</li>", Text); }
    }
}
```

Originally I thought you will need to display ordered list items in ordered list `<ol>` but I removed that part. This is code which builds html lists:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> CreateHtmlLists(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    ListItem currentItem = null;
    int listDepth = 0;

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        ListItem item;
        if (!ListItem.TryParse(line, out item)) {
            yield return line; // not list item, return as is
            continue;
        }

        if (currentItem == null || (currentItem.IsOrdered && !item.IsOrdered))
        {
            yield return "<ul>"; // start new nested list
            listDepth++;
        }
        else if (!currentItem.IsOrdered && item.IsOrdered)
        {
            yield return "</ul>"; // close nested list
            listDepth--;
        }

        yield return item.Html;
        currentItem = item;
    }

    while (listDepth > 0) { // close all parent lists        
        listDepth--;
        yield return "</ul>";
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var lines = text.Split('\n');
text = String.Join("\n", CreateHtmlLists(lines));
```

Output for your sample text:

```
Go to Original Budget screen,
<ul>
<li>Check if Original Budget is Original Budget CV</li>
<ul>
<li>Check if Remaining Budget is Remaining Budget CV</li>
<li>Check new field Exchange rate</li>
<li>Check new field Original Budget FC</li>
<li>Check new field Remaining Budget FC</li>
</ul>
<li>Check renamed field under Weekly Details:</li>
<ul>
<li>Check if In Flow is In Flow CV</li>
<li>Check if Out Flow is Out Flow CV</li>
<li>Check new field In Flow FC</li>
<li>Check new field Out Flow FC</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: First, THANKS! second, I try it, it works but this is the output
        Go to Original Budget screen, \n<ul>\n<li>Check if Original Budget is Original Budget CV</li>\n<ul>\n<li>Check if Remaining Budget is Remaining Budget CV</li>\n<li>Check new field Exchange rate</li>\n<li>Check new field Original Budget FC</li>\n<li>Check new field Remaining Budget FC</li>\n</ul>\n<li>Check renamed field under Weekly Details:</li>\n<ul>\n<li>Check if In Flow is In Flow CV</li>\n<li>Check if Out Flow is Out Flow CV</li>\n<li>Check new field In Flow FC</li>\n<li>Check new field Out Flow FC</li>\n</ul>\n</ul>

Comment: @JohnSmith if you don't need lines concatenated with `\n` then just join with empty string: `String.Join("", CreateHtmlLists(lines))`. I used new line character just for example